# Why am I getting a red wire for my output?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, modelsim

This is my code, my testbench, my simulation.

```
module multiplier (
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input signed [31:0] md,
    input signed [31:0] mt,
    output signed [63:0] rez
);

  reg signed [31:0] prod;
  reg signed [31:0] md_reg;
  reg signed [31:0] mt_reg;
  reg [31:0] contor;
  reg [1:0] state;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
      case (state)
        2'b00: begin
          md_reg <= md;
          mt_reg <= mt;
          contor <= 32'b0;
          prod   <= 32'b0;
          state  <= 2'b01;
        end
        2'b01: begin
          if (contor < 32'b1) state <= 2'b00;
          else state <= 2'b10;
        end
        2'b10: begin
          if (mt_reg[0]) prod <= prod + md_reg;
          mt_reg <= mt_reg >> 1;
          md_reg <= md_reg << 1;
          contor <= contor - 1;
          state  <= 2'b01;
        end
      endcase
  end

  assign rez = prod;
endmodule

module testbench;
  reg clk, rst;
  reg signed  [31:0] multiplicand;
  reg signed  [31:0] multiplier;
  wire signed [63:0] result;

  multiplier DUT (
      .clk(clk),
      .rst(rst),
      .md (multiplicand),
      .mt (multiplier),
      .rez(result)
  );

  integer t;

  initial clk = 0;
  initial begin
    rst = 0;
    #10;
    rst = 1;
    #10;
    rst = 0;
  end
  always #5 clk = ~clk;

  initial begin
    multiplicand = -123;
    multiplier = 456;
    t = 0;
  end

  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (t > 63) $finish;
    else t = t + 1;

    $display("t=%d, multiplicand=%d, multiplier=%d, result=%d", t, multiplicand, multiplier,
             result);
  end
endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the design code.

`result` is unknown (red x) because the design `rez` output is x.  `rez` is x because `prod` is x.  `prod` is x because it is declared as a `reg` type, and that type is initialized to x at time 0.  Since `prod` depends on `state`, which is also x, `prod` can't be assigned a known value until `state` is known.

The solution is to properly reset the registers.  Your design module has a `rst` input, but it is only used in the sensitivity list of the `always` block.  You need to also add an `if (rst)` clause as shown below:

```
module multiplier (
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input signed [31:0] md,
    input signed [31:0] mt,
    output signed [63:0] rez
);

  reg signed [31:0] prod;
  reg signed [31:0] md_reg;
  reg signed [31:0] mt_reg;
  reg [31:0] contor;
  reg [1:0] state;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (rst) begin
        state   <= 0;
        prod    <= 0;
        contor  <= 0;
    end else begin
      case (state)
        2'b00: begin
          md_reg <= md;
          mt_reg <= mt;
          contor <= 32'b0;
          prod   <= 32'b0;
          state  <= 2'b01;
        end
        2'b01: begin
          if (contor < 32'b1) state <= 2'b00;
          else state <= 2'b10;
        end
        2'b10: begin
          if (mt_reg[0]) prod <= prod + md_reg;
          mt_reg <= mt_reg >> 1;
          md_reg <= md_reg << 1;
          contor <= contor - 1;
          state  <= 2'b01;
        end
      endcase
    end
  end

  assign rez = prod;
endmodule
```

With these changes, `result` is no longer red (unknown).

---

Note: Your waveforms only showed the testbench signals.  To debug this type of problem, it is necessary to also view the internal signals in the design.

Comment: thank you! the result is no longer red anymore, but the output is 0, and it should be the result from the multiplication between the -123 and 456, can you tell me why?

Comment: @NistorCarina: You're welcome.  Since my answer solved the specific question you asked,  I recommend you [Accept](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)
 the answer, then open a new question.  Before you ask again, you should  look at all the internal signals in waveforms like I mentioned in my answer.  In your new question, post waveforms showing the internal signals, and ask a specific question as to why a signal does not have the value you expect.